# How to add a blank row in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, row, insertion

I am new to VBA and am trying to write VBA code that could add a new row if the last row is empty. However, when I use this code what happens is that it adds rows in locations that don't make sense. My last row is row 15. When I try to run the code for row 15 it adds a row after row 15 regardless whether it is empty or not, when I run the code for row 14 it adds a row after row 4 whether it is empty or not. When I run the code for row 13, it doesn't do anything whether it is empty or not.

```
'
' Add_A_Row Macro
' Adding a row to a row that is not blank
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A
'
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Dim rw As Range
  Dim RowCount As Integer

  RowCount = 0

  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  For Each rw In sh.Rows

    If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 15).Value <> "" Then
        rw.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlInsertFormatOriginConstant
    Debug.Print ("Hit")
    Exit For
    End If

Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: the number 15 refers to the column. In what column do you have to check if the cell is empty?

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the reasoning, is there more data below this last row? Why add a blank row where there already is a blank row?

Comment: Oh, I thought the 15 refers to the row number, I want to check if row 15 has data, then add a blank row. In my excel sheet every column represents a different department and from row 3-15 each department can write down their minutes of downtime. From row 15 onwards, there are multiple formulas that calculate the data they enter. 

Row 15 is the last row of the editable region for people to enter information. When at least one entry is in the last row I want a new row made so they can continue to document their downtime and not mess with manually adding a row.

Answer (score 0):

You might have swapped rows and columns in your condition. I would also suggest using a for loop instead of a foreach loop - with a for loop you have better control on what exactly is being done and in what order.

A general solution to your problem would be something along the lines of:

```vb
Sub AddRowsIfNotEmptyCell(wks As Worksheet, columnToCheck As Long)

    Dim i As Long

    'loop backwards in order not to analyze rows we just added
    For i = wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If wks.Cells(i, columnToCheck).Value <> vbNullString Then
            'insert a row below
            wks.Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason when I try to run this code, nothing happens. I am copying and pasting it into the terminal. Should I be doing something additional?

Comment: @SamuelDillper Yes. This code requires parameters (so it is flexible for any worksheet and any column). You can only run subs without parameters. So Create a new Sub() and inside it run `AddRowsIfNotEmptyCell(ActiveSheet,1)` - this will check column 1 in activesheet.